# Горизонтальное расположение кнопок

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt, qlayout, qpushbutton

Помогите пожалуйста с расположением кнопок. Сейчас стоят вертикально.

Нужно поставить горизонтально в одну строку, `LineEdit` и **`3`** кнопки.

Гуглил но решить проблему не смог, не силен в QT5

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
import os.path
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#import psycopg2

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите номер из 4х цифр')
        self.scan = QtWidgets.QPushButton('SCAN')
        self.scan.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)
        self.vnc1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('VNC1')
        self.vnc1.clicked.connect(self.VNC_PC1)
        self.vnc2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('VNC2')
        self.vnc2.clicked.connect(self.VNC_PC2)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['IP', 'Number', 'SSH', 'VNC'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        self.hbox_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.scan)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.vnc1)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.vnc2)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Не забудь подключить VPN ivoin', 3000)

    def func_connect(self):
        try:
            num = self.lineEdit.text()
            if not num.isdigit():
                self.statusBar().showMessage(
                    'Достустимо вводить только цифры, номер состоит из 4х цифр')
                return
            if len(num) != 4 :
                self.statusBar().showMessage('Номер состоит из 4х цифр, повторите ввод.')
                return

            rows = [('10.16.26.26', 2), ('10.16.26.27', 3), ('10.16.26.28', 1), ('10.16.26.29', 4)]
            for row in rows:
                pass
            print(rows)

            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(rows))
            for row,items in enumerate(rows):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))
##                print(str(items[1]))
                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'SSH')
                button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                    self.button_pushed_SSH(ip, n, btn))
                self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, button)

                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'VNC')
                button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                    self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))
                self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, button)
    ##        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Не удалось выполнить подключение. Повторите попытку позднее', msecs = 10000)
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Подключение не удалось, воможно магазин не в сети', msecs = 10000)
            self.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print( e )

    def button_pushed_SSH(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}')
    def button_pushed_VNC(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}')
    def VNC_PC1(self):
        pass
    def VNC_PC2(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Mono", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(480, 400)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Хотелось бы расположить примерно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget *widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment = Qt::Alignment())
>
> Эта версия добавляет данный виджет в сетку ячеек, охватывая несколько rows/columns..
> Ячейка начинается с fromRow, fromColumn охватывает строки rowSpan  и столбцы columnSpan. Виджет будет иметь заданное выравнивание.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
import os.path
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#import psycopg2

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите номер из 4х цифр')
        
        self.scan = QtWidgets.QPushButton('SCAN')
        self.scan.clicked.connect(self.func_connect)
        self.vnc1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('VNC1')
        self.vnc1.clicked.connect(self.VNC_PC1)
        self.vnc2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('VNC2')
        self.vnc2.clicked.connect(self.VNC_PC2)
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 4)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['IP', 'Number', 'SSH', 'VNC'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(100)
        
        self.hbox_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 3)         # +++
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1,3)             # +++
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.scan, 2, 0)                      # +++
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.vnc1, 2, 1)                      # +++
        self.hbox_layout.addWidget(self.vnc2, 2, 2)                      # +++
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Не забудь подключить VPN ivoin', 3000)

    def func_connect(self):
        try:
            num = self.lineEdit.text()
            if not num.isdigit():
                self.statusBar().showMessage(
                    'Достустимо вводить только цифры, номер состоит из 4х цифр')
                return
            if len(num) != 4 :
                self.statusBar().showMessage('Номер состоит из 4х цифр, повторите ввод.')
                return

            rows = [('10.16.26.26', 2), ('10.16.26.27', 3), ('10.16.26.28', 1), ('10.16.26.29', 4)]
            for row in rows:
                pass
            print(rows)

            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(rows))
            for row,items in enumerate(rows):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))
##                print(str(items[1]))
                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'SSH')
                button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                    self.button_pushed_SSH(ip, n, btn))
                self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 2, button)

                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'VNC')
                button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, ip=items[0], n=items[1], btn=button: \
                    self.button_pushed_VNC(ip, n, btn))
                self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 3, button)
    ##        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Не удалось выполнить подключение. Повторите попытку позднее', msecs = 10000)
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Подключение не удалось, воможно магазин не в сети', msecs = 10000)
            self.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print( e )

    def button_pushed_SSH(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}')
        
    def button_pushed_VNC(self, ip, n, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}: ip={ip}, n={n}')
        
    def VNC_PC1(self):
        pass
    def VNC_PC2(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Mono", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(480, 400)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за полный и быстрый ответ!

Comment: @elchako пожалуйста